# representation of if else condition in collaboration diagram

Tags: uml, staruml

I was wondering, how can one represent "if" statement on a collaboration diagram?

```
 if (somethingShouldBeDone) {
    //multiple conditions
   // Do it
  } else {
   // Do something else
  }
```

Can it be represented at all? The thing is ... in my code, fair amount of conditions are checked to determine a variety of actions. If i am going to show the actions, I'd like to explicitly state that actions are caused by particular events.

If possible create an image representation of a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use **guards** for representing the conditions that must be true for a message to be passed.

The following example is equivalent to

```
if (x<y) {
   object2.message1();
   object3.message3();
} else {
   object2.message2();
}
```

[image: Example]

Comment: thank you, and one more question, if there are n messages from object1 to object2 satisfying the if condition, do i need to mention [x<y] every time? i was thinking if there is any thing like ALT box which we use in sequence diagrams.

Comment: I cannot think of other way, but perhaps a sequence diagram is more appropriate for conveying that behavior.